# How to identify Background steps on Specflow?

Tags: c#, selenium, nunit, specflow

I know is possible to get steps information from specflow by using  `ScenarioStepContext.Current.StepInfo` but this doesn't return if the step is inside the Background block or not.

Is there a way to find out if the Step inside the Background or the Scenario/Scenario Outline?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the reason that you need this information?

Comment: Hi sorry, should have mentioned that. I'm building my report based on Specresults,but the thing is it shows undefined tests (the ones that has no steps yet, only the scenario created) as passed because it considers the Background steps as part of the scenario. So, basically this happens:

If scenario doesn't have a background step: It shows as pending. 
If scenario has a background step:It shows as passed.

I want to identify which step is a background step so I can leave it out of my report. Does it make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there is no way to get this information in the StepInfo.

But there is a possible (but little hacky) way to get this information. You have to look at the StackTrace and search there for an method named FeatureBackground(). This is the method in the generated code, that comes from the background.

This code will do the job:

```
var stackTrace = new System.Diagnostics.StackTrace();
var stackFrames = stackTrace.GetFrames();
bool isBackground = stackFrames.Where(x => x.GetMethod().Name == "FeatureBackground").Any();
```

Comment: Sorry the late reply. Worked perfectly! Thank you!